# Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3

I have created a very simple Vue 3 Component:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" :value="value" >
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  props:{
    value: {type: String, default: ''}
  }
});
</script>
```

With below HTML, I am trying to render the component in browser:

```
<div id="app">
  {{message}}

  <my-input></my-input>
</div>
```

This works correctly, but it fail when I try to pass `value` attribute to this component:

```
<my-input :value="message"></my-input>
```

This is error, I get in browser console:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '0' is not a valid attribute name.
at patchAttr (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:9333:18)
at patchProp (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:9539:11)
at mountElement (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6051:27)
at processElement (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6024:15)
at patch (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:5944:23)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6484:23)
at ReactiveEffect.run (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:580:31)
at setupRenderEffect (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6603:11)
at mountComponent (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6386:11)
at processComponent (https://unpkg.com/vue@next:6344:19)
```

Any remarks why I am getting this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `message` a variable or a string? If it's a string, you should do
```<my-input value="message"></my-input>```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue, but because of **another reason**. I wanted to pass attributes and properties from child to parent, so I've added  **v-bind="[$attrs]"** to the child, which **caused the error**

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ name }}
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
defineProps({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
    <Parent v-bind="[$attrs]" :class="{ 'active': modelValue }"/>
</template>
<script setup>
defineProps({
    modelValue: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
})
</script>
```

**Then I found out that attributes and properties are automatically passed through when one component is the root of the other.**